# What does it mean to brighten an image?

Tags: jpeg, image-manipulation, brightness

Courtesy of my optometrist, I now have images of my retinas. However, the images are a bit dark. I have RGB values for each pixel. In this setting, is brightening the image equivalent to increasing each of the RGB values slightly (toward white)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is it. Just apply a *multiplication factor* and not an offset to preserve colors.

If you are not concerned with *how bright* the image has to be then, that is all there is.

If you are, then you need to know if your image data is linear, logarithmic or follows a gamma curve. That depends on the image format but most scientific data is stored linearly.

Comment: It's in JPG format, but I've read it into a statistical computing program called R so I have the individual pixel RGB values. Does that tell you whether the image data is linear, logarithmic, or follows a gamma curve?

Comment: If the JPEG data is extracted from the JPEG and kept with the same values (8-bit per pixel-component), then it will *normally* follow a gamma curve. You should be able to confirm this by using a color picker. If the values were transformed, it could be anything! ...but I would suspect most tools would *want* to transform to linear but that requires higher precision output not to lose accuracy.