# Is there somewhere I can download sample images to use for practicing HDR techniques?

Tags: hdr, picture-samples, creative-commons

I'm a student and I have a final project concerning 'tone mapping technique'.

I have a simple question - is there a site where I can download the data base for an image HDR?

For example as we can see most authors use picture of the inside of a church to test the result of their tone mapping techniques.

Answer (score 5):

There are some HDR galleries here, which are under the Creative Commons license, so you could use these for experimentation.  They are already in .hdr file format.

http://pfstools.sourceforge.net/hdr_gallery.html

There is a series here of raw JPGs you can use (see the related files below this one).  Also Creative Commons.

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:StLouisArchMultExpEV%2B1.51.JPG

Also if you download the trial versions of some HDR programs, they will come with sample images you could use.  [Oloneo](http://www.oloneo.com/en/page/home.html) for example.

Finally, if you look for The HDR Book by RC Concepcion, he publishes [sample files](http://kelbytraining.com/books/hdr) on his website. They are intended for buyers of his book, but he provides a license to use them in practicing HDR techniques - if you are a student using them for educational purposes it would probably be fair use to use them.  He's a nice guy, you could ask permission :)

Comment: that pfstools gallery is neato.

Comment: That's interesting. Because, in [my question here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27943/how-does-software-raise-exposure-in-post-processing) I ask how PP executes EV in which the answer by Matt Grum was given as "simply multiplying the values". Which, to me, would shift the histograph up or down (like changing the amplitude of a wave form). However, in your link, it shifts LEFT/RIGHT for EV. Which now increases my understanding about dynamic range and why different EVs are needed for layering. But, I still don't know how PP executes +/- EV.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted some hdr source files packs on my DA account.  Each pack consists of a number of lossless TIFF images for use in the making of a hdr image.

Here is a link to the packs:
[HDR Source Pack Link](http://kippa2001.deviantart.com/gallery/48128960)

Answer (score 0):

This site has sets of RAW files you can play with:

http://farbspiel-photo.com/learn/hdr-pics-to-play-with